# LEFT JOIN with multiple tables. Poor performance

Tags: performance, join, union

I need to optimize the below query. I have a lot of records in tables: a, b, c, d and the query time is very long. Please for help.

```
SELECT main.*, items.*
FROM main
LEFT JOIN (
  (SELECT a.*, 1 AS `type` FROM a) UNION
  (SELECT b.*, 2 AS `type` FROM b) UNION
  (SELECT c.*, 3 AS `type` FROM c) UNION
  (SELECT d.*, 4 AS `type` FROM d)
)
items ON main.`to` = items.id AND main.`type` = items.`type`
WHERE main.id > 0
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts (since you don't mention DBMS it's gonna be as generic as possible).

1. The legs in the union are by definition (type) disjoint, so you can use `UNION ALL`. Many DBMS implement UNION with a sort which can be avoided with UNION ALL

   My guess is that the union of *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* is what is causing your pain because the DBMS evaluates this first (likely in a temporary table), and then joins that with *main*. By limiting the number of rows in this table you should see some performance improvement.
2. We know that the result of the query has a cardinality of less than or equal to 20. This means that *a* can't contribute with more than 20 rows. The same goes for *b*, *c* and *d*. By rewriting the query as:

   ```
     ( SELECT main.*, a.*, 1 as type
       FROM main
       LEFT JOIN a
           ON main.`to` = a.id 
          AND main.`type` = 1
       WHERE main.id > 0
       LIMIT 20
     )
   UNION ALL
     ( SELECT main.*, b.*, 2 as type
       FROM main
       LEFT JOIN b
           ON main.`to` = b.id 
          AND main.`type` = 2
       WHERE main.id > 0
       LIMIT 20
     )
   UNION ALL
     ( SELECT main.*, c.*, 3 as type
       FROM main
       LEFT JOIN c
           ON main.`to` = c.id 
          AND main.`type` = 3
       WHERE main.id > 0
       LIMIT 20
     )
   UNION ALL
     ( SELECT main.*, d.*, 4 as type
       FROM main
       LEFT JOIN d
           ON main.`to` = d.id 
          AND main.`type` = 4
       WHERE main.id > 0
       LIMIT 20
     )
   LIMIT 20 ;
   ```

   we likely prevent the assumed temp table from exploding. From this set that has 80 or fewer rows, we can then pick 20 with the last `LIMIT 20`.

Check if this improves things first.

Comment: Exactly, I can't limit because then i get NULL data.

Comment: I've edited your query with syntax that is allowed by MySQL, removing the derived table (and fixing the inner to LEFT joins).

Comment: Thanks, but how to add pagination to this query? `LIMIT 80, 20` for example.

Comment: You will need an order by for that to make sense. How do you want to order your result-set?